# Wondering about the correctness of a probability question from Elementary Probability Theory with Stochastic Processes.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> There are two kinds of tubes in an electronic gadget. It will cease to function if and only if one of each kind is defective. The probability that there is a defective tube of the ﬁrst kind is .1; the probability that there is a defective tube of the second kind is .2. It is known that two tubes are defective, what is the probability that the gadget still works?

If there are only two kinds of tubes and the probability that a defective tube is of type A is 0.1 then shouldn't it follow that the probability that a defective tube belongs to type B is 0.9 as a defective tube can either be of type A or type B?

Isn't the question kind of wrong?

Comment: The question is worded a bit differently. The gadget has (possibly) multiple tubes of both kinds. And the probability that one tube of type A fails is 0.1 and the possiblity that one tube of type B fails is 0.2. What you are refering to is the probability knowing that a tube has failed, the faulty tube being of tube A (which is not necessarily 0.1). In summary the probability that a there is a defective tube of type A is 0.1 and the probability that there is no defective tube of type A is 0.9 (which doesnt mean there is no defective tube of type B) if that makes sense

Comment: Well if that is the case, shouldn't the answer depend on another piece of information, that is how many tubes are there.

Comment: It may depend on how many tubes of each kind there are in the gadget: I would have thought the result may be anything between $0$ (if almost all the tubes are of one kind, so the two defective tubes are likely to be of the same kind) and $1$ (if there is exactly one of each kind so both must be defective)